# How can I find lat long of a point with a given lat long value and distance

Tags: java, geocoding

I have a point A (52.132781727864, -106,63492619991302). From point A i would like to get the lat, long of point B which is 5 km South from point A.

How can I get the the lat long of point B? I'm coding in Java.

**Edit: If the point is in South-East what should I do?**

Comment: I think ilya gave the correct answer (I assume the formular is correct). To understand the theory you can search the web for geographic coordinate systems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

5km in angles = ((5 / (6371 * pi)) * 180) =  0.0449660803. This number should be subtracted from the latitude. Longitude remains same.

PS. Thanks to Carlos Heuberger for correction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll have a look. But can you please mention one more thing? if the point is in a south-east position then what should I do?

Comment: not correct, that is only about 1.5 km. 1 latitude degree is 111.12 km, you have to subtract `5 / 111.12 = 0.04499640'

Comment: Assuming GPS (WGS84) near 52.132781727864° N, the surface distance per 1° change in latitude is [closer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Degree_length) to 111.2699 km/°.

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/) for earth surface geometry, as it factors in the earth as an ellipsoid (the earth is not a perfect sphere). In particular take a look at [GeodeticCalculator](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html) where you set the starting position and direction (azimuth and distance) and then get the destination position.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the question to "How can I find lat long of a point with a given lat long value, distance **and direction**", here an approximation for shorter distances (less than about 1000 km)

```
d = dist / 111.12      (1)
dlat = d * cos(dir)
latm = lat1 + dlat / 2
dlon = d * sin(dir) / cos(latm)

lat2 = lat1 + dlat
lon2 = lon1 + dlon
```

Where:
- `lat1` and `lon1` - the starting coordinates  (North and East are positive)
- `dist` - the distance in kilometers
- `dir` - the starting direction <sup>(2)</sup>
- `lat2` and `lon2` - the resulting coordinates

(1) *assuming the spherical earth model*
(2) *`dir = 135°` for South-East*

---

*based on [Astrosail - Mittelbreitenverfahren](http://astrosail.de/de/static/tutorial/best3.php?cat=42)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a little time along. Since in my case the original data was in UTM, the product only had to work in a given zone, and the distance to add was not very big, all I had to do was calculating sinus and cosinus and adding easting and northing to the initial poing